# How to correctly install wkhtmltopdf on debian 64 bit?

Tags: linux, installation, odoo, wkhtmltopdf, apt-get

I am trying to install wkhtmltopdf, but when I do:

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

I get :

```
Preparing to unpack wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wkhtmltox (0.12.1) over (0.12.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
  wkhtmltox depends on libjpeg-turbo8; however:
  Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wkhtmltox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox
```

So I tried:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8
```

Then I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libjpeg-turbo8' has no installation candidate
```

I'm using a 64 bit debian.
I browsed the web to find a solution but infortunately didn't find any answers.
How can I get the libjpeg-turbo8?

EDIT:

So I tried `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` despite the fact it wasn't recommended.

The probleme with `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` is that the version isn't always the good one and we should use 0.12.1

But:

```
root@dev01:/opt/odoo/modules_scndf# apt-cache policy wkhtmltopdf 
wkhtmltopdf:
  Installed: 0.12.1-2
  Candidate: 0.12.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 0.12.1-2 0
         500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Version seems to be the good one even with `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` but when I launch my print on odoo I still get

```
Unable to find Wkhtmltopdf on this system. The report will be shown in html.
```

Which means he didn't installed as it should have.

EDIT 2:

Now when I try to print the report, I get a popup:

```
Wkhtmltopdf failed (Error code : -6). Message : The switch 
--header-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be 
ignored.The switch --footer-html, is not support using unpatched qt,
and will be ignored.QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

Comment: this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50153456/26130

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ubuntu and Debian packages are compatible most times but not in all cases, i think this is the trouble you're having you're trying to use the Ubuntu's `.deb` for Debian instead you should get the Debian specific file, (it works for both jessie and wheezy)

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-wheezy-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i  wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-wheezy-amd64.deb
```

Then in the `/etc/init.d/openerp-server` or `/etc/init.d/odoo-server` script(s), depending on your which one you have

add  `/usr/local/bin` to the front of path environment variable for example,

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin,
```

This tells odoo where to look for system binaries it requires or optionally you can copy the files to `/usr/bin`, if you don't want to mess with those files

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmlto* /usr/bin/
```

**Download page for wkhtmltopdf**: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: I get this error while trying to do the sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-wheezy-amd64.deb

dpkg: error processing package wkhtmltox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox

Comment: run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, if the dependency problem is not resolved run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f`

Comment: gna.org seems to be down - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gna! which says:  `The service was shut down in 2017.` Any suggestions on alternative download sources?

Comment: Yes there's an alternative source...from github directly, Example https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/0.12.1/ I've updated the url in the answer

Comment: Here came Odoo 11, still using the version **0.12.1** but not running on debian Jessie or Wheezy anymore. So here, some addition to install this version of **wkhtmltopdf on Stretch** :
You need to **download** ( find repo on google and `wget` ) and **install** ( using `dpkg -i` ) :
`libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u7_amd64.deb`
`libpng12-0_1.2.49-1+deb7u2_amd64.deb`
`libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb`

Then you can use the answer.

Comment: In my case I needed to download `libjpeg8` package from https://packages.debian.org/es/wheezy/amd64/libjpeg8/download before installing `wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-wheezy-amd64.deb` with `dpkg`. After that it worked perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

That's works for me in Debian Stretch:

```
$ sudo apt-get -q update
$ sudo apt-get -qy install --no-install-recommends wget
$ wget -nv -O /tmp/wkhtmltox.deb https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get -qy install /tmp/wkhtmltox.deb
```

Comment: thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 15):

I'm running Debian Stretch 9.2 64bit and I succeeded with the following:

```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base gvfs colord glew-utils libvisual-0.4-plugins gstreamer1.0-tools opus-tools qt5-image-formats-plugins qtwayland5 qt5-qmltooling-plugins librsvg2-bin lm-sensors 
    sudo wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
    sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/
    sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin/
```

Then check the installation with:

```
    wkhtmltopdf -V
```

Which should return:

```
    wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)
```

Comment: worked for me flawlessly on docker running python:3.7-slim-buster. thanks!

Comment: I have used this method with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 in Ubuntu 20.04 and it works for me

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to use wkhtmltopdf with an existing debian based docker image. But I faced

> Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed

Finally I fixed this by installating libjpeg-turbo8 using dpkg. Below are the docker commands:

```
ARG  jpeg=libjpeg-dev
ARG  ssl=libssl-dev
ENV  CFLAGS=-w CXXFLAGS=-w

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libfontconfig1-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    $jpeg \
    libpng-dev \
    $ssl \
    libx11-dev \
    libxext-dev \
    libxrender-dev \
    python \
    zlib1g-dev \
    xfonts-75dpi \
    xfonts-base \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.6-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.6-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
RUN apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
sudo apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmlto* /usr/bin/
```

Comment: This error occurs on "sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
 wkhtmltox depends on libjpeg-turbo8; however:
  Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wkhtmltox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to broken wkhtmltopdf package.

You can try using commands below to install them -

First remove the broken wkhtmltopdf from your system. using -

```
sudo apt-get purge wkhtmltopdf
```

Then try using the commands below -

```
cd /tmp/
```

then Download the recommended version of wkhtmltopdf for Odoo server, currently 0.12.1: -

```
sudo wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

then install the package using dpkg :-

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

To function properly we’ll need to copy the binaries to an adequate location:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
```

Comment: gna.org seems to be down - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gna! which says:  `The service was shut down in 2017.` Any suggestions on alternative download sources?

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://nightly.odoo.com/extra/wkhtmltox-0.12.1.2_linux-jessie-amd64.deb
dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1.2_linux-jessie-amd64.deb
/etc/init.d/odoo restart
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 0):

The download path got changed to the following ! Please have a try with the below link.

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

and then do install it by following command

sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

---

Second Option

sudo wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz

tar -xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz

Copy files to /usr/bin/ and Restart all running Odoo services

sudo cp ./wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin/

sudo cp ./wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Devuan ascii` (which is `Debian stretch` based) and it's enough to

```
sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf
```

During install it pulled in some Qt5 packages as well. There's no need to copy around the executable from `/usr/local/bin/` to `/usr/bin/` because it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 12, I did:

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-3/wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-3.bookworm_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-3.bookworm_amd64.deb
```